# Camunda Process Definition Deployment via API

Tags: camunda

I'm trying to deploy a process definition from a file using the following code

```
    DeploymentBuilder deploymentBuilder = repositoryService.createDeployment().name(definitionName);
    deploymentBuilder.addInputStream(definitionName, definitionFileInputStream);
    String deploymentId = deploymentBuilder.deploy().getId();
    System.out.println(deploymentId);
```

The above code runs successfully and the new deploymentId is printed out.

Later, I tried to list the deployed process definitions using the following code

```
    List<ProcessDefinition> definitions = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().list();
    System.out.println(definitions.size());
```

The above code runs successfully but the output is always 0.

I've done some investigations and found that in the `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY` table an entry with the corresponding `deploymentId` exists and the `BYTES_` column contains that contents of the definitions file.

I have also found that there is no corresponding entry found in `ACT_RE_PROCDEF` table.

Is there something messing? from the API and the examples I found it seems that the above code shall suffice, or is there a missing step?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that the issue was related to `definitionName` [(thanks thorben!)](https://forum.camunda.org/t/process-definition-deployment-via-api/3919) as it has to ends on either `.bpmn20.xml` or `.bpmn`.

After further testing, the suffix is required for the following `definitionName` of the code

```
    deploymentBuilder.addInputStream(definitionName, definitionFileInputStream);
```

Leaving the following `definitionName` without the suffix is fine

```
    repositoryService.createDeployment().name(definitionName);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you forget the `isExecutable` flag on your deployed process definitions. Please check if your process model contains a `isExecutable` flag. If you use the camunda modeler simply set this option in the properties panel of the process.

If you call `#deploy()` with non-executable definitions an deployment will created, but the process definition are not deployed since they are not executable.

On the latest version of camunda platform (7.7), a new method called [#deployWithResult()](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.7/org/camunda/bpm/engine/repository/DeploymentBuilder.html#deployWithResult()) was added to the `DeploymentBuilder`. This method returns the deployed process definitions, so it is easy to check if process definitions are deployed.